# Moving my PayPal app from sandbox to live

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have tested my PayPal app in the sandbox and I am happy with it.

I would like now to move my app to production.

I am reading this: https://developer.paypal.com/reference/production/

But it's not clear what to do for me.

Do I have to create another app or just move my tested app to live by pressing the "Sandbox/Live" button?

When I go to: https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/applications/sandbox

I see my "Default Application" (System generated, no actions available).

This is this "Default Application" that I used for my tests.

If I click on "Default Application" I can see the "SANDBOX API CREDENTIALS":

- Client ID
- Secret

These are the credentials I used for my tests.

Also, I see a "Sandbox/Live" button that is currently set to "Sandbox".

When I press this button, it is set to "Live".

I now see "LIVE API CREDENTIALS" but the credentials are missing.

I don't see the new credentials.

Moreover, if I go back to: https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/applications/sandbox

There's also a message "You're in sandbox mode.".

It means I am still not in "Live".

If I try to press the "Sandbox/Live" button, it does not want to go live.

So, I am stuck.

How to move my PayPal app to production please?

Thank you.

Best regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found how to:

- Go to https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/
- Press the "Sandbox/Live" button to set it to "Live"
- Go to "Apps & Credentials"
- Press the "Create App" button

You'll get your live credentials.

Then edit your app as explained on https://developer.paypal.com/reference/production/ :

- Replace the old sandbox credentials with the new live credentials
- Replace the old url "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com" with the new url "https://api-m.paypal.com"

And it should be live now.

I have to try with real money to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

For others who might have the same problem: if clicking the upper-right "Live" toggle does not work to switch to live, ensure:

- The live account you are signing in with is of type 'business' (not premier, developer, personal)
- The primary **email address is confirmed** in [the paypal.com profile](https://www.paypal.com/businessprofile/settings/email)